# Can operator new return before construction is finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, new-operator

Constructing objects on the heap is deceptively simple-looking task in the C++ language. When the code

```
T* object = new T();
func(object);
```

is called, it is my understanding that memory must be first allocated, then initialized, and finally have the class's constructor called on it. Furthermore, the virtual table of the object is not necessarily available until *after* construction is complete.

My question is this: Can `operator new` return a pointer to allocated/initialized memory before an object has finished being constructed, such that `func(...)` operates on a not-entirely constructed object? The answer to this question has implications for a multi-threaded library which I am developing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `operator new` *must* return said pointer before the object *starts* being constructed. Where would it be constructed without said pointer?

Comment: Of course, but I meant something akin to "return the pointer, and continue execution within the current scope". I edited the original post in an effort to clarify my meaning a bit.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You need to learn about memory ordering.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm trying my best to phrase the question. If you could point me to a resource on memory ordering pertinent to the question, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If these are on the same thread of execution then of course the construction is complete before func is called. I suspect you wouldn't have tagged it "multithreading" if this were really a single-threaded example, though.

Comment: ^ Correct. Please see my comments on Pete Becker's answer for further details on the multithreading aspect.

Answer (score 6):

`operator new` allocates memory. The `new` keyword (as used in the sample code) uses `operator new` to allocate memory, then constructs the object in that memory. And, yes, in a multi-threaded application without proper synchronization, the pointer value can become visible in other threads before the side effects of the constructor have taken place. That's because each processor can have a separate cache, and the pointer value may get read into the cache before the constructor side effects get read into the cache. Read about "double-checked locking" for more details.

Comment: Suppose that it is the function call of `func(object)` which *makes* the object visible to other threads though. In this case, is it still possible that there will be threading issues?

Comment: @DanM.Katz - if the function makes the object visible with proper synchronization, then it will work fine. If not, then you can't rely it. No amount of talking around it will remove the requirement for synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for your help Pete; a bit of clarification may help to shed some light on my question. In my particular application, I am inserting a `new`ly constructed object into a concurrent queue (it is a single-producer-multiple-consumer system). Once a worker thread pulls the object from the queue, it is performing a virtual function call on it. However, this call is triggering a runtime error, stating that it is executing a "pure virtual function call", indicating, to my understanding, that the construction of the object has not yet finished.

Comment: Is my assumption that the constructor has finished prior to being inserted into the concurrent queue insufficient synchronization? If so, might you be able to explain why?

Comment: Let me know if you think that this should be a separate question. :-)

Comment: @PeteBecker: +1 for giving the search term to know the subject better instead of just 'showing off' the knowledge without telling where one learned it.

Comment: Don't ignore Pete's caveat that you must make the object visible **through some means of synchronization**. It's not enough to reason about it and think "it must be that way". In fact Herb Sutter gave a fairly in-depth talk about this titled "Atomic Weapons" where he points out that unless you properly synchronize (i.e. avoid data races), you are not allowed to reason about your program at all. It's available online.

Comment: @PeteBecker, could you recommend what type of synchronization might be appropriate for my use case?

Comment: @DanM.Katz - that's really a different question. The problem you describe in your comment probably has nothing to do with synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

The `object` won't point to an object before the construction is made. The `new T()` won't return before it is finished.

I guess that Pete Becker is correct with the cache problem though...

Answer (score 1):

I think there's confusion between `operator new()` and `T* object = new T();` producing the value of `object`.

If we look at it very simplisticly (and this is just for illustration purposes, not meant to be a precise definition of how the C++ compiler actually does things), we can break down `T* object = new T();` into a couple of pieces:

```
 void *temp = ::operator new(sizeof(T));  // Now we have SPACE for a T object. 
 (T*)temp->T();       // Construct the contents of T. 
 object = (T *)temp;    // assign `object`.
```

(Note for pedants: The code above is NOT meant to be valid C++, nor is it "How you take one C++ statement and makes it into three" - it is meant to describe what happens in that one line in a form that someone with reasonable, but not expert knowledge of C++ can understand).

It happens in this order, and unless your constructor starts a thread that does some work that "completes the construction", you can not have a value in `object` that isn't completely constructed.

Comment: Your `Construct the contents of T` syntax i weird, and wouldn’t work. The C++ syntax for calling a constructor explicitly is via placement-new. Of course I realise that your code is supposed to be illustrative only but why not use the actually existing syntax?

Comment: Better now? - I changed the "argument" to "cast method call".

Comment: Does that work? (Edit: no.) Why not just coalesce the last two lines to `T* object = new (temp) T();`?

Comment: The WHOLE point was to describe what happens during the single line of construction with new - if I make calls to new again, then it's not going to be clear that we're getting memory, then constructing, then assigning the pointer.

Comment: Then how about calling `std::allocator::construct`, which does the same internally, to make it clear that this is a constructor call. I’m just not very comfortable with posting C++ syntax which looks like it works but doesn’t, when there’s a perfectly valid C++ syntax for this.

Comment: My point was partly to keep it very simple - calling `std::allocator::construct` means that the reader (and I) know what `std::allocator::construct` actually does. The whole point of `(T *)temp->T();` is to show that "we're calling the constructor with the address we got from `operator new`). The purpose of this code is NOT to show "Here's what you do if you want to construct some code that is doing the job of the original line in several lines".

Comment: And to be sure nobody tries to copy my code and complain when it doesn't compile: I have made it clearer with a note.

Comment: Then why not use pseudocode wholesale? `(T*)temp->T();` is hardly clear. Why not just `construct temp as T`? Just my opinion …

Answer (score 0):

> memory must be first allocated, then initialized, and finally have the class's constructor called on it.

I'm not aware of the middle step. For your form `operator new` is called then thhe constructor on the memory returned by the former.

> Furthermore, the virtual table of the object is not necessarily available until after construction is complete.

It is available -- in some sense (the standard does not mandate VMT at all, just behavior), in simple terms during construction the class behaves as if it was the 'most derived' for the active ctor.  Virtual calls can be issued but they land on Base::foo from Base::Base(), and if called from the init list care must be taken that some parts are not yet constructed.

> My question is this: Can operator new return a pointer to allocated/initialized memory before an object has finished being constructed?

`operator new` *always* runs and finishes before the ctor is started.

But you might mean the `new operator` as in your question. That returns only when everything is done, the ctor done its job.